# I cant understand the error messages : encripting data

Tags: c++

I have an error message when submitting a program, but I cannot understand the cause. Please tell me where and how to fix it.

## Problem

There is a trick to encrypt the data and use a word as its key. Here's how it works: First, choose a word as the key, such as TRAILBLAZERS. If the word contains repeated letters, only the first one is kept, and the rest are discarded. Now, the modified word is listed below the alphabet, as shown below:

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

T R A I L B Z E S

Then arrange the letters in the alphabet that do not appear in the modified word after the modified word to get the coding table:

A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

T R A I L B Z E S C D F G H J K M N O P Q U V W X Y

Therefore, based on the key of TRAILBLAZERS, if our original message is ATTACK, it will be encrypted as TPPTAD.
Input requirements: input key and original information, output encrypted information

Example 1: Input TRAILBLAZERS ATTACK and output TPPTAD.

Input : Enter a line, including the input key and the original information (both capital letters), separated by spaces.

Output : Output a line, representing the encrypted information

## Error message

1. The data is opened too small, resulting in access to a memory area that should not be accessed
2. A division by zero error occurs
3. A large array is defined in the function, causing the program stack area to be exhausted
4. The pointer is used incorrectly, resulting in access to a memory area that should not be accessed
5. It is also possible that the program throws an unreceived exception

## Code

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char list1[26] = {0}, list2[26] = {0};//暗号化する文字列, 新たなアルファベット表//original information, table
    int size = 0; //入力した文字の文字数 //the number of characters of key
    char gomi;
    bool check = false;// 前に同じ文字が出たかどうか // whether appeared twice
    for(int i = 0; ; ++i){
        gomi = getchar();
        for(int j = 0; j <= i; ++j){
            if(gomi == list2[j]) check = true;
        }
        if(gomi == ' ') break;//空欄で終了 //when there is a space, break;
        else if(check == true) {i -= 1; check = false; continue;}//前に同じ文字があれば飛ばす// if appear same character twice, continue;
        else list2[i] = gomi;
        size += 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; ; ++i){//暗号化する文字列の格納 //original information
        gomi = getchar();
        if(gomi == '\n') break;//改行で終了//when there is a \n, break;
        else list1[i] = gomi;
    }
    int num = 65;//ASCⅡコード // ASCⅡ
    for(int i = size; i < 26; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if(num == list2[j]){num += 1; j = -1;}//前に同じコードがあれば確認を最初からやり直し //if there is the same character before, check from the front again
        }
        list2[i] = num;
        num += 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; ++i){
        if(list1[i] == 0) break;//暗号化する文字列の出力が終わったら終了 //finish the output
        cout << list2[list1[i] - 65];
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Those are pretty good messages. Beats the hell out of "Error. Redo from start."

Comment: That list you show doesn't seem to be any known or common error messages. Where are they coming from? Do you get build errors? Then copy-paste them in full and complete into the question. Do you get unexpected out? Then copy-paste it into the question, together with the *expected* output as well as the input. Do you get crashes? Again we need to know the input, and if possible please try to catch the crash with a debugger.

Comment: Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Unrelated: Refrain from using magic numbers. The meaning of `'A'` is a hell of a lot easier to infer (and not screw up) than `65`.

Comment: Its a homework of university, I got those error messeges when I submitted my code to the university server. On my laptop, this code works well, I don't know why the server gave me those error messages. I've already asked my TAs, but I'm not good at Chinese so I couldn't really understand what they said, so I asked here(my university is in China, and my mother tong is not Chinese:()

Comment: One error message is `A division by zero error occurs` but there is no division in the code. Is this a general list of runtime errors that *might* happen, to cause a program failure? Also `A large array is defined in the function` but there is no large array.

Comment: "On my laptop, this code works well." That doesn't rule out the possibility of *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) is pure evil. Since the behaviour is undefined, the program can do anything and whatever it does doesn't have to be consistent.

Comment: Your very first loop, if there's no space in the input the outer loop will never break and you have the very real risk of going out of bounds of `list2`. Going out of bounds is undefined behavior. Also the [`getchar`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/getchar) function returns an `int` which is very important if you ever want to compare against `EOF` (which you definitely need to do).

Comment: Thanks all, I've tried your advises and finally passed!!! Seems the getchar() occured that error. I didn't know about the EOF, so that I didn't compare with EOF. Anyways thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char list1[256] = {0}, list2[26] = {0};//暗号化する文字列, 新たなアルファベット表//original information, table
    int size = 0; char gomi;//入力した文字の文字数//the number of characters of key
    bool check = false;// 前に同じ文字が出たかどうか// whether appeared twice
    for(int i = 0; ; ++i){
        gomi = getchar();
        if(gomi == EOF) break;
        for(int j = 0; j < i; ++j){
            if(gomi == list2[j]) check = true;
        }
        if(gomi == ' ') break;//空欄で終了//when there is a space, break;
        else if(check == true) {i -= 1; check = false; continue;}//前に同じ文字があれば飛ばす
        else list2[i] = gomi;                                    //if appear same character twice, continue;
        size += 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; ; ++i){//暗号化する文字列の格納//original information
        gomi = getchar();
        if(gomi == EOF) break;
        if(gomi == '\n') break;//改行で終了//when there is a \n, break;
        else list1[i] = gomi;
    }
    int num = 'A';//ASCⅡコード
    for(int i = size; i < 26; ++i){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            if(num == list2[j]){num += 1; j = -1;}//前に同じコードがあれば確認を最初からやり直し
        }
        list2[i] = num;
        num += 1;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 256; ++i){
        if(list1[i] == 0) break;        //暗号化する文字列の出力が終わったら終了
        cout << list2[list1[i] - 'A'];  //if there is the same character before, check from the front again
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the part where `getchar` returns a **`int`**. This is actually very important for the comparison against the `int` constant `EOF`.

Comment: I still not very understand. Should I wirte as     while((gomi = getchar()) != EOF){}    ?

Comment: What I mean is that `gomi` needs to be an `int`. It's implementation-defined if `char` is signed or unsigned. And if it's unsigned then you will have a situation where `EOF != EOF`.